# Dimension of a subspace of a matrix space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T belongs to set of all $m*n$ matrices over R. Let V be a subspace of set of all $n*p$ matrices. Then what is the dimension of V = {X : TX = 0} ?
So this is like the solution space of T which is n - rank(T). But here X is not a column vector, but a matrix of order $n*p$. So how can we determine the dimension ? 
The answer is p*(n - rank(T)). Can someone please explain how ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of the $p$ columns of a matrix in $V$ you can independently choose any vector that lies in the (standard) nullspace $N$ of $T$, i.e. $V$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $p$ copies of $N$. The dimension of $V$ is thus $p(n-\operatorname{rank}T)$.

Comment: @math You can choose $p$ vectors, any way you like. Linear dependence does not apply here because the vectors are not added together.